# need bam file for pilon

Tags: sam, sequence-analysis, assembly, conversion, genome-index

I just ran an assembly on yeast genomes using Flye and I want to polish those assemblies with Pilon but it requires a sorted BAM file.

How do I make a BAM file of the resulting assembled.fasta?

Comment: What reads do you have? Only long read or short read or whatever? You need to align the starting reads to your assembly and then supply _that_ bam, as implied by the user172818 answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run a short-read mapper. For example:

```
bwa index assembled.fasta
bwa mem -pt16 assembled.fasta read1.fq.gz read2.fq.gz \
  | samtools sort -m4G -@4 -o align.bam -
```

Comment: This is good if the user has Illumina, that isn't clear (though it is implied by using pilon).